# How can I execute a get request in php?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, get, themes

I'm using WordPress as my CMS and I'm trying to alter a theme for a post page. I've edited the html on the backend, but how specifically (and in simple terms) can I make a 'get' call in php for the page to load a title and feature image inside the  I've created?

Answer (score 0):

To display a title from within The Loop you can use the function `the_title`. To display a featured image you can use the function `the_post_thumbnail`.

More info:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail